# Custom keras layer similar to dot product

Tags: python, tensorflow, keras, layer

I would like to make a custom Keras layer that acts similar to a dot product, but not exactly the same. I have an input of shape

```
(None, 10, 18, 32)
```

And I would like to obtain a shape

```
(None, 18, 32)
```

I would like to have one single vector of weights (one, for each row, so the shape would be (10, 1) or (1, 10)). And then multiply the vector of weights so that each row is multiplied by one weight and then added together. My objective with this layer is to assign one weight to each row and then identify which rows are more important (hence, will have greater weight).

The shape 10 is fixed (I have a specific matrix coded that way), but the dimension with shape 18 depends on the topology of the network.

How could I code this with Keras? Additionally, can I add restrictions to those weights? I would like the weights to be non-negative and less than one, if I could impose such thing.

Edit to share what I am trying to do. This is the layer that I created:

```
class Linear(keras.layers.Layer):
    def __init__(self, units=1, input_dim=10):
        super(Linear, self).__init__()
        w_init = tf.random_normal_initializer()
        self.w = tf.Variable(
            initial_value=w_init(shape=(units, input_dim), dtype="float32"),
            trainable=True,
        )

    def call(self, inputs):
        A = K.permute_dimensions(inputs,(0,2,1,3))
        A = K.dot(self.w, A)
        A = K.squeeze(A,0)
        return A
```

But I get this summary (I don't understand how is it possible to obtain a 10 there in the dimension with the code that I've done, but ok).

```
linear_24 (Linear)           (None, 10, 18, 32)        10
```

And then of course, since I'm doing something wrong I obtain the following error:

```
InvalidArgumentError:  Matrix size-incompatible: In[0]: [32,576], In[1]: [5760,100]
     [[node dense_9/MatMul (defined at /usr/local/lib/python3.6/dist-packages/keras/backend/tensorflow_backend.py:3009) ]] [Op:__inference_keras_scratch_graph_62482]

Function call stack:
keras_scratch_graph
```

My model:

```
from keras.models import Sequential
from keras.layers import Conv2D, Dropout, MaxPooling2D, Flatten, Dense, InputLayer, BatchNormalization
from keras.callbacks import LearningRateScheduler

n_outputs = 5
batch_size = 64


model = Sequential()
model.add(InputLayer(input_shape=(nbld, resolution, 1)))

model.add(Dropout(0.25))
model.add(Conv2D(filters=64, kernel_size=3, activation='relu', padding='same', input_shape=(nbld, resolution, 1)))
model.add(MaxPooling2D(pool_size=(1,2)))


model.add(Conv2D(filters=32, kernel_size=3, activation='relu', padding='same'))
model.add(MaxPooling2D(pool_size=(1,2)))

model.add(Dropout(0.25))
model.add(Conv2D(filters=32, kernel_size=2, activation='relu', padding='same'))
model.add(MaxPooling2D(pool_size=(1,2)))

model.add(BatchNormalization())

model.add(CustomLayer())
model.add(Flatten())
model.add(Dense(100, activation='relu'))
model.add(Dense(n_outputs, activation='softmax', name="visualized_layer"))
model.compile(loss='categorical_crossentropy', optimizer='sgd', metrics=['accuracy'])

model.summary()
change_lr = LearningRateScheduler(scheduler)
history = model.fit(x=X_train, y=y_train, epochs=10, validation_data=(X_test, y_test), callbacks=[change_lr])
```

And the summary of the model:

```
Model: "sequential_29"
_________________________________________________________________
Layer (type)                 Output Shape              Param #   
=================================================================
dropout_85 (Dropout)         (None, 10, 150, 1)        0         
_________________________________________________________________
conv2d_85 (Conv2D)           (None, 10, 150, 64)       640       
_________________________________________________________________
max_pooling2d_85 (MaxPooling (None, 10, 75, 64)        0         
_________________________________________________________________
conv2d_86 (Conv2D)           (None, 10, 75, 32)        18464     
_________________________________________________________________
max_pooling2d_86 (MaxPooling (None, 10, 37, 32)        0         
_________________________________________________________________
dropout_86 (Dropout)         (None, 10, 37, 32)        0         
_________________________________________________________________
conv2d_87 (Conv2D)           (None, 10, 37, 32)        4128      
_________________________________________________________________
max_pooling2d_87 (MaxPooling (None, 10, 18, 32)        0         
_________________________________________________________________
batch_normalization_29 (Batc (None, 10, 18, 32)        128       
_________________________________________________________________
custom_layer_2 (CustomLayer) (None, 10, 18, 32)        10        
_________________________________________________________________
flatten_11 (Flatten)         (None, 5760)              0         
_________________________________________________________________
dense_11 (Dense)             (None, 100)               576100    
_________________________________________________________________
visualized_layer (Dense)     (None, 5)                 505       
=================================================================
Total params: 599,975
Trainable params: 599,911
Non-trainable params: 64
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

here a possibility with a simple custom layer

```
class CustomLayer(Layer):
    
    def __init__(self):
        super(CustomLayer,self).__init__()
        
    def build(self, input_shape):
        
        self.W=self.add_weight(name="custom_weight", shape=(1,input_shape[1],1,1),
                               initializer="normal")
        
    def call(self, x):
        
        x = tf.nn.softmax(self.W, axis=1)*x 
        # apply a softmax if u want them non-negative and less than one otherwise ignore or change it
        x = tf.reduce_sum(x, axis=1)
                
        return x
```

how the layer works

```
batch_dim = 32
X = np.random.uniform(0,1, (batch_dim,10,18,32)).astype(np.float32)

CustomLayer()(X).shape # (batch_dim, 18, 32)
```

example in a model

```
X = np.random.uniform(0,1, (5,10,18,3))
y = np.random.uniform(0,1, 5)

inp = Input((10,18,3))
x = Conv2D(32, 3, padding='same', activation='relu')(inp)
x = CustomLayer()(x)
x = Flatten()(x)
out = Dense(1)(x)

m = Model(inp, out)
m.compile('adam','mse')
m.fit(X,y, epochs=3)

# get the weights
tf.nn.softmax(m.get_weights()[-3], axis=1)
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer, it looks promosing but for sure I am doing somethin wrong. I just copied your code and added your layer into my network and the following error ocurrs:
InvalidArgumentError:  Matrix size-incompatible: In[0]: [32,576], In[1]: [5760,100]
  [[node dense_10/MatMul (defined at /usr/local/lib/python3.6/dist-packages/keras/backend/tensorflow_backend.py:3009) ]] [Op:__inference_keras_scratch_graph_64165]

Function call stack:
keras_scratch_graph

Comment: I think that it's a problem of the model... there is the possibility to know ho it looks like

Comment: I added in my original post my model and how the summary looks like (with your custom layer). It works fine if I don't add any custom layers, I was already using this model to do some predictions.

Comment: simple paste and copy your code... no problem using it: https://colab.research.google.com/drive/1XVZOLL3pbJBzKDI9uEb5bi53H1OoSkqI?usp=sharing don't forget to upvote and accept as answer ;-)

Comment: So it appears that the problem must be with Keras and TensorFlow, because the only difference between your code and mine is that I use everything with import keras and yours uses tensorflow.keras
Thank you for your help!